# Creating report getting failed in ColdFusion 2018

Tags: coldfusion, report, coldfusion-2018, cfreport

I have tried the below code for creating report in ColdFusion, but it gives failure like in the screenshot,

```
 <cfchart format="png" name="chartImage">
    <cfchartseries type="bar" query="chart" itemcolumn="title" valuecolumn="level">
 </cfchart>

 <cfset chartImageFile = getTempDirectory() & '\' & createUUID()>
 <cfset fileWrite(chartImageFile, chartImage)>

 <cfreport format="pdf" template="report.cfr" name="grid">
    <cfreportparam name="reportTitle" value="#reportType.title#">
    <cfreportparam name="chartImage" value="#chartImageFile#">
 </cfreport>

<cfset fileDelete(chartImageFile)>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried giving your image file name `chartImageFile` a proper extension? Change this `<cfset chartImageFile = getTempDirectory() & '\' & createUUID()>` to this `<cfset chartImageFile = getTempDirectory() & '\' & createUUID() & '.png'>`.

Comment: Might want to check the other answer on this question too - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64466965/1636917.  looks like you copied that code verbatim so maybe it will work for you too.

Comment: What is the value of `ReportType.title`?